# Why is my Android Studio project not opening with an activity?

Tags: java, android, maven, android-activity, groovy

When I hit "New Project" in Android Studio, I get a menu that asks me what type of project I want to make. The options are Java, Maven, Gradle, Groovy, Griffon, Static Web, Empty Project. I want to create a new project with an activity in order to start building an android app but the two options that seem remotely valid here are "Java" and "Empty Project". Choosng either of these does not create an activity for me. I tried to create an activity once the project was created by right clicking on the src file ->New->??? but I do not have an option here to create one. I am new to Android Studio could someone please help me as to why I cannot do this?

I looked at some video tutorials online and they all seemed to start with the correct menu, so online resources were of no help really...

Comment: I'm really curious as to why this question got downvoted...

Answer (score 1):

I had this probelm either. 
At last, I found that I hadn't activated the Android Support plugin.
Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right I believe you just select empty project to start a new android project. Androids website has an excellent tutorial to get beginners started: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I used this tutorial and it worked for me:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/78574/android-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1
Basicly you just click file\new project and you should be able to configure it and at the end you select "blank activity", which adds the activity in question. While I never saw a menu like the one you describe, it could be possible you just didn't download the important files with the sdk manager? You need the basic files and an api of your choice. It is also explained in the tutorial.

Comment: I see a big difference with my studio vs. the one in the guide you provided. Upon opening Android Studio, my Quick Start menu says Create New Project, Import Project, Open Project... while in the guide his Quick Start guide says Start a new Android Studio Project, Open an existing Android Studio Project, Import an Android code sample...why are we looking at 2 different things here?

Comment: Just to go sure, yours is fully updated? Mine definitely is. Otherwise I really don't know but might look into this out of curiosity.

Comment: Other users had this problem too, but I didn't find a solution other than "resetting" android studio, so maybe just try reinstalling.

Comment: I checked some box and it worked. Sadly, I don't remember what it was! However, it did have something to do with updating....I followed the train of thought to update everywhere I could and that worked. Thanks for your help!